# Nagios/NSCA: Command file '/var/nagios/rw/nagios.cmd' does not exist

Tags: centos6, nagios

I installed nagios on Centos and I also want to enable [NSCA](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/NSCA--2D-Nagios-Service-Check-Acceptor/details) on the host.  The client is already configured and is sending data (I can see it when I tail the logs).  However, I'm seeing the following error message in the log by NSCA

`Command file '/var/nagios/rw/nagios.cmd' does not exist, attempting to use alternate dump file '/var/nagios/rw/nsca.dump' for output`

I browsed to `/var/` and there was no "`nagios`" folder.  So I created one.  I also created a /rw/ folder.  I restarted nagios but `nagios.cmd` wasn't created. I did a `chown` and `chgrp` to nagios on those folder but that didn't help.

First off, how come `/var/nagios/rw/` was never created during the installation?  Can someone think of a way make this work so nagios creates the `nagios.cmd` file (NSCA is looking for it to input data)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the next foolio....The actual path to the `nagios.cmd` is `/var/spool/nagios`.  Once I set the right path in the `NSCA.cfg` file, everything started working.  Remember, that nsca puts in a file `nsca.dump` which has all the data.  `nsca.dump` needs to consumed by `nagios.cmd`.